# Hadoop on Windows with Eclipse error when starting data node

Tags: java, windows, eclipse, hadoop, cygwin

I am following this tutorial http://v-lad.org/Tutorials/Hadoop/14%20-%20start%20up%20the%20cluster.html

I am at the "start the cluster" step but when I start the data node(when I execute the command: bin/hadoop datanode) I get the following error:

```
$ bin/hadoop datanode
12/07/04 23:53:53 INFO datanode.DataNode: STARTUP_MSG:
/************************************************************
STARTUP_MSG: Starting DataNode
STARTUP_MSG:   host = halgarci-WS/10.21.144.26
STARTUP_MSG:   args = []
STARTUP_MSG:   version = 0.19.1
STARTUP_MSG:   build = https://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/hadoop/core/branches/bra                             nch-0.19 -r 745977; compiled by 'ndaley' on Fri Feb 20 00:16:34 UTC 2009
************************************************************/
12/07/04 23:53:54 ERROR datanode.DataNode: java.io.IOException: Expecting a line                              not the end of stream
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.DU.parseExecResult(DU.java:181)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell.runCommand(Shell.java:179)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell.run(Shell.java:134)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.DU.<init>(DU.java:53)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.DU.<init>(DU.java:63)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.FSDataset$FSVolume.<init>(FSDa                             taset.java:325)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.FSDataset.<init>(FSDataset.jav                             a:681)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode.startDataNode(DataNod                             e.java:291)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode.<init>(DataNode.java:                             205)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode.makeInstance(DataNode                             .java:1238)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode.instantiateDataNode(D                             ataNode.java:1193)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode.createDataNode(DataNo                             de.java:1201)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode.main(DataNode.java:13                             23)

12/07/04 23:53:54 INFO datanode.DataNode: SHUTDOWN_MSG:
/************************************************************
SHUTDOWN_MSG: Shutting down DataNode at halgarci-WS/10.21.144.26
************************************************************/
```

Any advice on how I can resolve this error?

Thanks!!

Answer (score 3):

not sure if you have resolved the problem.
The 'du' command Hadoop uses is the windows/system32/ builtin one, not the cygwin/bin/du.exe.
I just removed the Windows builtid du.exe, and let haddop use cygwin's, then everything worked.

Answer (score 1):

The `DU` class executes the command `du -sk <dirPath>` and tries to parse its results.

The exception you get indicates, that the result (standard out) is empty. Here the parsing code for reference:

```
  protected void parseExecResult(BufferedReader lines) throws IOException {
    String line = lines.readLine();
    if (line == null) {
      throw new IOException("Expecting a line not the end of stream");
    }
    String[] tokens = line.split("\t");
    if(tokens.length == 0) {
      throw new IOException("Illegal du output");
    }
    this.used.set(Long.parseLong(tokens[0])*1024);
  }
```

If you run `du`on the command line you can see that std-out is empty if the specified directory does not exist. So I would assume this is the case here.

Have you checked that the datanode data directory (configured via `dfs.data.dir`in `hdfs-site.xml`) exists?

Comment: How do I check that the datanode data directory exists?  Not sure where it would be located.  

Not sure if this helps but in my "C:\cygwin\home\halgarci\hadoop-0.19.1\conf" folder there is a file called hadoop-site.xml

Comment: A) You could add a configuration entry in `hadoop-site.xml` for `dfs.data.dir`. B) You could set a breakpoint in org.apache.hadoop.fs.DU.getExecString() and run the datanode in the debugger. That why you can see what directory `du` is called for and what the result is when you execute the command in the cygwin prompt. C) You could find out what the default value for `dfs.data.dir` is by looking it up in a file called `hadoop-default.xml`, which should be somewhere in your hadoop distribution. (Using the debugger is probably the best way. You wont have to guess the command.)